# What's the idiomatic way to avoid channel deadlocks in a recursive worker pool chain?

Tags: go

Suppose you have a basic toy system that finds and processes all files in a directory (for some definition of "processes"). A basic diagram of how it operates could look like:

[image: toy example]

If this were a real-world distributed system, the "arrows" could actually be unbounded queues, and then it just works.

In a self-contained go application, it's tempting to model the "arrows" as channels. However, due to the self-referential nature of "generating more work by needing to list subdirectories", it's easy to see that a naive implementation would deadlock. For example (untested, forgive compile errors):

```
func ListDirWorker(dirs, files chan string) {
    for dir := range dirs {
        for _, path := range ListDir(dir) {
            if isDir(path) {
                    dirs <- path
                } else {
                    files <- path
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we imagine we've configured just a single List worker, all it takes is for a directory to have two subdirectories to basically deadlock this thing.

My brain wants there to be "unbounded channels" in golang, but the creators don't want that. What's the correct idiomatic way to model this stuff? I imagine there's  something simpler than implementing a thread-safe queue and using that instead of channels. :)

Comment: Note that you process files, not directories. If you have a file processor and a files channel, you can simply recursively process directories, and send every file to the channel. Nothing will deadlock.

Comment: Yup I get that, this is just a really easy toy example, so it's easier to discuss a "producer/consumer chain where a consumer can be its own producer"

Comment: Let's say it's configurable at startup, though I don't think it matters. For any pool size, I can think of a case where it breaks (pool size n --> have n+1 subdirectories, each of which have a couple of subdirectories).

But in general, it needs to work even if n = 1.

Comment: You can't really do this with a fixed sized pool. One option is to create additional goroutines. For your example, this might be creating a new goroutine whenever you write to the dirs channel. Another option is to have an intermediate goroutine that makes sure there are always active consumers and not all goroutines are producers.

Comment: The real-world applications follow multi-level architechture.  Bottom layer visits the file system and sends file paths to the next layer that processes files. The next layer, if needed, sends the results to the upper layer. Each layer might include any number of workers. And no deadlocks - all arrows in the workflow graph are directed only upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a very similar problem to solve. Needed:

- finite number of recursive workers ([bounded parallelism](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines#bounded-parallelism))
- [content.Context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) for early cancelations (enforce timeout limits etc.)
- partial results (some goroutines hit errors while others did not)
- crawl completion (worker clean-up etc.) via recursive depth tracking

Below I describe the problem and the gist of the solution I arrived at

---

Problem: scrape a HR LDAP directory with no pagination support. Server-side limits also precluded bulk queries greater than 100K records. Needed small queries to work around these limitations. So recursively navigated the tree from the top (CEO) - listing employees (nodes) and recursing on managers (branches).

To avoid deadlocks - a single `workItem` channel was used not only by workers to read (get) work, but also to write (delegate) to other idle workers. This approach allowed for fast worker saturation.

**Note:** not included here, but worth adding, is to use a common API rate-limiter to avoid multiple workers collectively abusing/exceeding any server-side API rate limits.

---

To start the crawl, create the workers and return a results channel and an error channel. Some notes:

- `c.in` the `workItem` channel must be unbuffered for delegation to work (more on this later)
- `c.rwg` tracks collective recursion depth for all worker. When it reaches zero, all recursion is done and the crawl is complete

---

```
func (c *Crawler) Crawl(ctx context.Context, root Branch, workers int) (<-chan Result, <-chan error) {

    
    errC := make(chan error, 1)

    c.rwg = sync.WaitGroup{}   // recursion depth waitgroup (to determine when all workers are done)
    c.rwg.Add(1)               // add to waitgroups *BEFORE* starting workers
    c.in = make(chan workItem) // input channel: shared by all workers (to read from and also to write to when they need to delegate)
    c.out = make(chan Result)  // output channel: where all workers write their results

    go func() {

        workerErrC := c.createWorkers(ctx, workers)

        c.in <- workItem{
            branch: root,   // initial place to start crawl
        }

        for err := range workerErrC {
            if err != nil {
                // tally for partial results - or abort on first error (see werr)
            }
        }
        // summarize crawl success/failure via a single write to errC
        errC <- werr // nil, partial results, aborted early etc.
        close(errC)
    }

    return c.out, errC
}
```

---

Create a finite number of individual workers. The returned `error` channel receives an error for each individual worker:

```
func (c *Crawler) createWorkers(ctx context.Context, workers int) (<-chan error) {

    errC := make(chan error)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(workers)

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        i := i
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            var err error

            defer func() {
                errC <- err
            }()

            conn := Dial("somewhere:8080") // worker prep goes here (open network connect etc.)

            for workItem := range c.in {
                err = c.recurse(ctx, i+1, conn, workItem)
                if err != nil {
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        c.rwg.Wait() // wait for all recursion to finish ...
        close(c.in)  // ... so safe to close input channel ...
        wg.Wait()    // ... wait for all workers to complete ...
        close(errC)    // .. finally signal to caller we're truly done
    }()

    return errC
}
```

---

`recurse` logic:

- for any potentially blocking channel write, always check the `ctx` for cancelation, so we can abort early
- `c.in` is deliberately unbuffered to ensure delegation works (see final note)

---

```
func (c *Crawler) recurse(ctx context.Context, workID int, conn *net.Conn, wi workItem) error {

    defer c.rwg.Done() // decrement recursion count

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()                      // canceled/timeout etc.

    case c.out <- Result{ /* Item: wi.. */}:  // write to results channel (manager or employee)
    }
    
    items, err := getItems(conn) // WORKER CODE (e.g. get manager employees etc.)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, i := range items {
        // leaf case
        if i.IsLeaf() {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return ctx.Err()

            case c.out <- Result{ Item: i.Leaf }:
            }    
            continue
        }

        // branch case
        wi := workItem{
            branch: i.Branch,
        }

        c.rwg.Add(1) // about to recurse (or delegate-recursion)

        select {
        case c.in <- wi:
            // delegated to another worker!

        case <-ctx.Done(): // context canceled...
            c.rwg.Done() // ... so undo above `c.rwg.Add(1)`
            return ctx.Err()

        default:
            // no-one to delegated to (all busy) - so this worker will keep working
            err = c.recurse(ctx, workID, conn, wi)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

Delegation is key:

- if a worker successfully writes to the worker channel, then it knows work has been delegated to *another* worker.
- if it cannot, then the worker knows all workers are busy working (i.e. not waiting on work items) - and so it must recurse itself

So one gets both the benefits of recursion, but also leveraging a fixed-sized worker pool.